# CGAL : Can I use alpha shape to simplify a path?

Tags: cgal

I would like to get the outter part of a robot trajectory (the boundaries of this trajectory).

I read in several posts that the best way to retrieve the boundary of a point cloud is to use alpha shapes.

So I use the alpha shape implementation of CGAL.

[image]

Above picture repressent :

- Blue dot : The robot trajectory
- Red cross : Vertexes of the optimal alpha shape
- Cyan edges : Edges of the optimal alphashape.

Optimal alpha is according to the [CGAL documentation](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Alpha_shapes_2/classCGAL_1_1Alpha__shape__2.html#aec257cfd1bb47e49366f3ca589a56959) the alpha for which :

- All data points are either on the boundary or in the interior of the regularized version of the alpha shape.
- The number of solid component of the alpha shape is equal to or smaller than 1.

If I increase alpha, I got the convex hull (as expected).
But I can't find an alpha that will give me the following boundary (the black one in the figure bellow) :

[image]

So my question is :

**Does the black shape in figure above can be found thanks to alpha shapes with the blue point as input ?**

For those who wants to see how to use the CGAL python binding to generate alpha shapes, here is my code :

```
def computeAlphaShape(val):
    alpha_shape = Alpha_shape_2(points, 10000.0)
    it = alpha_shape.find_optimal_alpha(1)
    optimal_alpha = it.next()
    alpha_shape.set_alpha(val)
    print("Optimal alpha : " + str(optimal_alpha) + " current alpha : " + str(val))
    if val == 0:
        salpha.set_val(optimal_alpha)
        return

    print("Solid components : " + str(alpha_shape.number_of_solid_components()))

    drawResult(alpha_shape)


salpha.on_changed(computeAlphaShape)


def drawResult(alpha_shape):
    ax.clear()
    ax.plot(X, Y, 'ob')
    edges = alpha_shape.alpha_shape_edges()
    while edges.hasNext():
        eresX = []
        eresY = []

        edge = edges.next()
        segment = alpha_shape.segment(edge)
        eresX.append(segment.source().x())
        eresY.append(segment.source().y())
        eresX.append(segment.target().x())
        eresY.append(segment.target().y())
        classe = alpha_shape.classify(edge)
        color = 'g-'
        if classe == EXTERIOR:
            color = 'b-'
        elif classe == INTERIOR:
            color = 'r-'
        elif classe == SINGULAR:
            color = 'y-'
        elif classe == REGULAR:
            color = 'c-'
        ax.plot(eresX, eresY, color)
    vertices = alpha_shape.alpha_shape_vertices()
    v_res_x =[]
    v_res_y = []
    while vertices.hasNext():
        vertex = vertices.next()
        v_res_x.append(vertex.point().x())
        v_res_y.append(vertex.point().y())

    ax.plot(v_res_x, v_res_y, '+r')
```

Answer (score 2):

For such a task I would use the [simplification package](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polyline_simplification_2/index.html) if the already have the segments and the [2D reconstruction package](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Optimal_transportation_reconstruction_2/index.html#Chapter_Optimal_Transportation_Curve_Reconstruction) is you only have points.

Alpha-shape will work well only if the density of the points is uniform, by picking all edges that are not EXTERIOR. Alpha should be the squared distance between 2 points on the trajectory (just a bit more to be sure the edge is picked). I'm not even sure about what will be the outcome if you have some parts with a small local feature size. In such a case, only SINGULAR and REGULAR edges should be picked.